# WPF: Is there a sort of XAML tag that behaves like the HTML span element?

Tags: wpf, field, required

Coming from ASP.NET, this WPF stuff is just confusing.  All I want to do is put a red asterisk by a label to indicate a required field.  Playing around with stuff, I found that this actually does the trick:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label Foreground="Red" Content="*" /><Label Content="Heavy Weight" />
</TextBlock>
```

Being that I just came up with this, I am not convinced it's the academic route a seasoned WPF developer would take.  Additionally, this markup puts a huge amount of white space in between the asterisk and the label.  In HTML, a span element would just render right beside its next sibling element.  FYI, I tried putting a label within a label, but VS2010 kept barking about "The property 'content' is set more than once".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that you actually put two elements one after the other. You need to put them into a container.

Just a sample code of a sentence with red asterisk I did recently:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
            <TextBlock Text="Display name"/>
            <TextBlock Text="*" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text=":"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

There, everything is in a `StackPanel`, so property 'content' will actually be set once (if you don't specify a group panel such as this one, you'll have to add only one element)

Comment: This is definitely that more academic route I was looking for. However, although more appropriate, the text is all bunched up in the upper-left of my grid cell.  When I change the textblocks to labels, I still get the whitespace.  I am chalking it up to a padding issue. If I make padding = 0, the element moves as far down and to the left as it can. I am thinking I could remove padding from just the left or right. I'll check into it.

Comment: It is normal that your text is stuck on the top-left -- you specify it: `HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"`. Change these two values to Center, and it should do the work for you

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would be more appropriate:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Span Foreground="Red">*</Span>Heavy Weight
</TextBlock>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613554%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an overview of what can go into a TextBlock's content, more specifically [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

one more way is

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="*" />
    <Run Text="Heavy Weight" />
</TextBlock>
```

btw
Damascus's solution adds more UI Elements.
with CodeNaked's solution, its difficult to databind the Text.

Comment: forgot to mention. Run's Text property can be databound only after certain .net version.